# Traefik headers hostsProxyHeaders meaning

Tags: django, traefik, cookiecutter-django

What does Traefik's Headers hostProxyHeaders configuration do?

I am looking at traefik.yml settings from django-cookiecutter ([link](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/c650acc19bd7aadeaca9ba4fa2a17a13a8ab0e68/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/traefik/traefik.yml#L66))

```
  middlewares:
    csrf:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders
      # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
      headers:
        hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]
```

I understand that it is required for CSRF header which django uses. Why is this configuration required and what happens if this configuration is not set?